# HIVE not connecting with Python?

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

I have installed Hadoop and HIVE on windows 10 by following tutorials,

https://exitcondition.com/install-hadoop-windows/ & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npyRXkMhrgk respectively.

Both Hadoop and HIVE are running on my machine, I have been able to put files in HDFS and run queries in HIVE, but when I try to connect HIVE with ***python*** it gives different errors. Such as

```
from pyhive import hive

hive.Connection(host='localhost',port=10000,auth='NOSASL')
```

it gives following error:

```
 TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

I have tried *impala* as well but it did not work.

How can I connect python with hive, is it possible on windows 10 or should I shift to linux?

Comment: Please show those processes are running and debug with beeline first

Answer (score 0):

Pyhive had issues with auth = NOSASL in past.. not sure whether it got fixed .

Try hdfs3 python lib

```
conda install hdfs3
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
hdfs=HDFileSystem(host='localhost',port=9000)
```

More info available here..

https://medium.com/@arush.xtremelife/connecting-hadoop-hdfs-with-python-267234bb68a2